# using ng-view for hightly dynamic content?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm working on a website that allows you to search for different products, for example laptops. This is my index div:

```
<div  class="content" id="main">

    <div id="search-wrap">
        <div id="logo"><a href="#"><h1>seach</h1></a></div>

        <form id="search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search " autofocus ng-model="query"/>
        </form>

        <div style="border: solid 1px blue" ng-show="query">
            <ul ng-repeat="x in [] | range:10">
                {{ query }}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have not yet implemented angular js on this but I'm thinking about how to do it. I'm not sure how to approach this, since its a complex site. Once a user searches for something, they will get results from a product. Will i have to create a different ng-view?

I'm just going by something i read online:

> A page gets one ng-view. Assuming you have a single page application, this means you get one view. Use it wisely. Give some thought to what should be in the view. Is this your main content window or is this more of a navigation? Is the actual content (HTML) of this section highly dynamic? These are important decisions to make early in the development of your application if you have more than one distinct content area on your page.

Sorry if my question doesn't make sense, just not sure what to ask.  Any tips will help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You better try using `ng-view` and you would get more idea how it works.

There can be one `ng-view` in a page and it is tightly integrated with the url. When you change urls in browser, effective you are loading a different view into the `ng-view` area. These are configured using the `$routeProvider`.

`ng-view` is like the central content theme\area. Other views including sub-views for the main view and left nav, top nav footer is loaded using `ng-include` directive which has capability to compile and load any html chunk from server or locally.

For complex routing needs please have a look at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which supports nested views.

Answer (score 0):

For complex view you can try something like this

```
$stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'login.tpl.html',
            access: 0
        })
    .state('multiple view', {
            url: '/main',
            access: 1,
            views: {
                '@': {
                    templateUrl: 'view1.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'view1Controller'
                },
                'page@dashboard': {
                    templateUrl: 'page.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'pageController'
                }

            }
        })
```

[More Info](http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-start-with-angular.html)

Comment: This is not a standard component on AngularJS. This is part of `ui-router` library.